# Android Studio Master Detail List onClick not working

Tags: android, android-studio

I am new to android development so may be i am missing something elementary here, but after almost 2 days of googling I am still unable to figure out the cause.

I have followed the following [article](http://inducesmile.com/android/android-fragment-masterdetail-flow-tutorial-in-android-studio/) to create my project, except that I am invoking this activity from another activity when a button is clicked.

I have also created my own List adopter `public class MyListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<MyData>`  and in the `getView()` method of this adapter I am actually providing a different representation like below.

```
if (convertView == null) {
   convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.my_list_view, parent, false);
}
```

this all works fine I am able to bind the data and its displaying the results on the list without any issues. Now I want to show the details of selected `MyData` when the user clicks on the list item, but this is just not working no matter what I try.

I have ensured that my activity is implementing the callback interface like below:

```
public class MyItemListActivity extends FragmentActivity
        implements MyItemListFragment.Callbacks
```

and the callback itself is also very simple:

```
public interface Callbacks {
     public void onItemSelected(MyData item);
}
```

also on my `MyItemListFragment` the `onAttched` is  correctly hooked up `mCallbacks = (Callbacks) activity;`

What I really notice is that the following function is just not called when I click on the list item:

```
@Override    
public void onListItemClick(ListView listView, View view, int position, long id) {
       super.onListItemClick(listView, view, position, id);
       MyData data = DataContent.ITEMS.get(position);
       // Notify the active callbacks interface (the activity, if the
       // fragment is attached to one) that an item has been selected.
       mCallbacks.onItemSelected(data);
}
```

my fragment that displays the list item looks like this:

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/myitem_list"
    android:name="path.MyItemListFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    tools:context="path.MyItemListActivity"
    tools:layout="@android:layout/list_content" />
```

and the actual custom adapter view `my_list_view` looks like below:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >....</RelativeLayout>
```

I can see that its missing the `android:onClick` tag here, but not sure if that is the cause and also who needs to implement this handler as there is no direct context on this layout.

Any help is really appreciated.

Regards
Kiran